# How to use awk and print 3rd column that contains both 'db2' and 'SAP' strings?

Tags: text-processing, awk

```
cat ost_lvdd01_inbound_DD990_East.csv | awk -F',' ~ /db2/&/sap/ ; print $3
```

Input

```
/ost_lvdd01_inbound/1472930000/WPW-DBS003795.amer.warnerbros.com_1472938570_C1_IM:1472938570:/PROD_SQL_TXN_LOG:4:1:
/ost_lvdd01_inbound/1474990000/wbaubp10.warnerbros.com_1474999154_C1_TIR:1474999154:/W_PR_DB2_1M_SAP_User:4:1:
/ost_lvdd01_inbound/1475200000/EPWDB00004.tw.tweis.net_1475204316_C1_TIR:1475204316:/W_PR_SQL_TX_1M_1800_1h:4:1:
```

I need only column which contains both the strings DB2 & SAP, in this case it is 2 row.

Comment: only if the 3rd column contains both strings, or if both strings are in the line anywhere?

Comment: /ost_lvdd01_inbound/1472930000/WPW-DBS003795.amer.warnerbros.com_1472938570_C1_IM:1472938570:/PROD_SQL_TXN_LOG:4:1:
/ost_lvdd01_inbound/1474990000/wbaubp10.warnerbros.com_1474999154_C1_TIR:1474999154:/W_PR_DB2_1M_SAP_User:4:1:
/ost_lvdd01_inbound/1475200000/EPWDB00004.tw.tweis.net_1475204316_C1_TIR:1475204316:/W_PR_SQL_TX_1M_1800_1h:4:1:

I need only column which contains both the strings DB2 & SAP, in this case it is 2 row.

Comment: you should use the edit link on your post, so it can be formatted and read all in one place...

Comment: try `awk -F: '$3 ~ /DB2/ && $3 ~ /SAP/{print $3}'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "easy to understand" answer (though Awk is better if you have other things to do as well):

```
cut -d, -f3 file.csv | grep DB2 | grep SAP
```

Answer (score 0):

```
awk -F: '$3~/DB2/ && $3~/SAP/{print $3}' ost_lvdd01_inbound_DD990_East.csv
```